# Automatically add rel="noopener" to hyperlinks set to open in a new window

Tags: wygwam, fieldtype, links, ee5, textarea

Is there an easy fix that will append `rel='noopener'` to every link that’s set to open in a new window when using the hyperlink button in a text area field?

[image]

Comment: You can look into a CKEditor plugin to do it, or make a simple one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for an easier approach and wrote a Javascript function instead which looks for any links with an attribute of `target="_blank"` and adds `rel="noopener"`.

```
function relnoopener() {
    const a = document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]');
    a.forEach(function(element) {
        if (!element.hasAttribute('rel')) {
            element.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener');
        }
    });
}
```